# What is the use of Frobenuis inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I was studying Linear Algebra from the famous textbook Linear Algebra by Stephen H. Friedberg, Arnold J. Insel, and Lawrence E. Spence and reached the inner product of a vector space, I understand the intuition behind the standard dot product in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but he also mentioned Frobenuis inner product over the space of the square matrices. Is there any intuition I can understand, given that I only have the basic knowledge of algebra?

Comment: It is related to the standard dot product. You can relate an $n \times n$ matrix to a vector in $\mathbb{F}^{n^2}$ by "vectorizing" the matrix, (some map  $\mathrm{vec}: M_n(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}^{n^2}$, which given a matrix outputs a column vector which is the columns of the matrix stacked on top of one another. Then the Frobenius inner product between two matrices is the standard dot product between their respective vectorizations.

Comment: The Frobenius product can be defined for real matrices in terms of the trace function
$$\langle X,Y\rangle = {\rm Tr}(X^TY)$$
This holds not just for square matrices, but for two matrices of _any shape_ (as long as they're the same).

Comment: @greg Thanks for your comment. I know the definition, but I want the intuitive meaning behind it. Like the dot product in R^3, there is a geometrical intention behind it. So is there an intuitive meaning behind the Frobenius product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Frobenius inner product is a way to extend the concept of the dot product from vectors to matrices and it provides a measure of similarity between two matrices, just as the dot product does for vectors.
The Frobenius inner product is directly related to the Frobenius norm, which is a measure of a matrix's "size" or "magnitude" and is defined as the square root of the Frobenius inner product of the matrix with itself.
Like the dot product for vectors, it can be used to measure the similarity or difference between two matrices, like comparing image data and other matrix-formatted information, for example in machine learning.
The Frobenius inner product is also used in the study of spectral properties of matrices (such as in SVD and PCA), as it relates to the trace operator and eigenvalues, so it's very important in dimensionality reduction in Data Science.

Imagine two matrices A and B as a vectors in a high-dimensional space, where each element of the matrix corresponds to one dimension in that space. The Frobenius inner product of two matrices treats the matrices as if they were long vectors of their elements and computes the dot product of these "vectors."
As an example, if you think of two images represented by matrices, the Frobenius inner product could be interpreted as a measure of how similar these two images are, pixel by pixel. If the images are identical, their Frobenius inner product will be the square of the Frobenius norm of one of them. If the images are completely different in every pixel, their Frobenius inner product would be closer to zero.